# WebRequest does not Contain a definition for "Referer"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does this code say that `System.Net.WebRequest` does not contain definition for "Referer".

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
request.Referer = "";
```

Comment: Do you mean a compile time error or that it doesn't get submitted as part of the request?

Comment: Because it [doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `WebRequest`, use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx). `HttpWebRequest` has the property `Referer`.

`WebRequest` class doesn't have such property.

```
HttpWebRequest  request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
request.Referer ="http://www.microsoft.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class does not have a property called `Referer`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest_properties.aspx

What you looking for is probably [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.